# Generate Pandas intercept product for interactions in multiple regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to build an interaction of two factors from two dataframes as is commonly done in multiple linear regression to look for multi-level interactions.  We're trying to build a permutation table of all possible column products from each dataframe:

edit: originally I said intersect, I meant interaction

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A1":[1,1,1,1],
                    "A2":[1,2,3,4],
                    "A3":[3,3,3,3]})
df1
   A1  A2  A3
0   1   1   3
1   1   2   3
2   1   3   3
3   1   4   3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B1":[1,2,3,4],
                    "B2":[10,10,10,10]})

df2
   B1  B2
0   1  10
1   2  10
2   3  10
3   4  10
```

My desired output of df1 `* df2 would be:

```
   A1*B1  A1*B2  A2*B1  A2*B2  A3*B1   A3*B2
0      1     10      1     10      3      30
1      2     10      4     20      6      30
2      3     10      9     30      9      30
3      4     10     16     40     12      30
```

I feel like I'm really missing something about dot products.  But every which way I try them I just get "matrices are not aligned" when I try `df1 @ df2`

I get the outcome I don't want from `df1.T @ df2`

```
df1.T @ df2
    B1   B2
A1  10   40
A2  30  100
A3  30  120
```

I've tried a few list comprehension methods, but I can't seem to make the magic happen.

Comment: please mention what you have tried

Comment: @yashaswik the question states: "I get the outcome I don't want from `df1.T @ df2`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
out = pd.DataFrame(
    np.hstack(np.multiply(df1.values[None, :, :].T, df2.values)),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, df2.columns]),
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  A1      A2      A3    
  B1  B2  B1  B2  B1  B2
0  1  10   1  10   3  30
1  2  10   4  20   6  30
2  3  10   9  30   9  30
3  4  10  16  40  12  30
```

Comment: I tried both this and @quang Hoang's answers.  Ultimately this method doesn't require the conversion of df1 and df2 to floating point before multiplication (int*float is understood)

Comment: ultimately went with this for column names rather than MultiIndex:
`colnames = np.array(['{}*{}'.format(i,j) for i in df1.columns for j in df2.columns])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) which is a general extension of matrix product:

```
# the directive `'ij,ik->ijk'` means taking product of 
# the ij-th element in df1 and the ik-th element in df2
# then put that at ijk-th position
# we then just need to unfold the last 2 dimension into one
output = pd.DataFrame(
    np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', df1, df2).reshape(df1.shape[0],-1),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, df2.columns])
)

print(output)
```

Output:

```
  A1      A2      A3    
  B1  B2  B1  B2  B1  B2
0  1  10   1  10   3  30
1  2  10   4  20   6  30
2  3  10   9  30   9  30
3  4  10  16  40  12  30
```

Comment: This worked really well, but ultimately required conversion of both input dfs to float before the calc, whereas @adrej Kesely's answer handled `int*float` conversions.